# Roster are not show online after attach function strophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I have connected strophe from openfire and show roster in chatbox it is working fine.Also I can show roster when call attach function but not show online status.

```
conn.attach(jid, sid, rid, function () {
    XMPPChat.connection = conn;
    XMPPChat.connection.resume();
    jQuery(document).trigger('connected');
});
```

Yes connected function is defined

```
jQuery(document).bind('connected', function () {    
    var iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
    XMPPChat.connection.sendIQ(iq, XMPPChat.on_roster);
});
```

Comment: Did you defined "connected" event for "document"?

Comment: Yes connected function is defined.

Comment: @Devendra: in order to receive online status of your buddies (in the roster) you have to subscribe to their presence status. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38988580/online-and-offline-users-using-strophe-js-in-real-time/39052968#39052968

Comment: Hello beaver, Thank you for your reply.it is useful.Can you help on manage session in strophe for new tabs or pages?