# Online and Offline users using strophe.js in real time

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I am using **strophe.js** javascript client library for connecting to **xmpp** server(**openfire**) using below code.

```
var BOSH_SERVICE = 'http://127.0.0.1:7070/http-bind/';
 connection = new Strophe.Connection(BOSH_SERVICE);

  connection.connect("jid",
                   "password",
                   onConnect);
```

and callback function(onConnect) as below :

```
function onConnect(status)
{
    if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is connecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL) {
    log('Strophe failed to connect.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTING) {
    log('Strophe is disconnecting.');
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.DISCONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is disconnected.');
    $('#connect').get(0).value = 'connect';
    } else if (status == Strophe.Status.CONNECTED) {
    log('Strophe is connected.');
    log('ECHOBOT: Send a message to ' + connection.jid + 
        ' to talk to me.');

    connection.addHandler(onMessage, null, 'message', null, null,  null); 
    connection.send($pres().tree());
    console.log($pres().tree());

    }
}
```

i am successfully connect to server using this code and **no problem until this**.

**Problem** : updating user list with status in real time.

Let me explain my problem :

I want to show list of online and offline users with real time update.(something similar to showing chat apps.)

ex. Suppose there is 3 users A,B and C. and all are online (logged-in)

Now suppose user A get disconnect or go offline then how user B,C get notified with status of user A ?. and change status of user A to offline without refresh in user B and C list.

is there is any method in strophe.js that will automatically call when some one get connect or dis-connect. or should i need to write my own?

i am not sure but there is something with roster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subscribe to presence for your buddies using this Strophe API:

```
connection.send($pres({
  to: jid,     // buddy jid
  type: "subscribe"
}));
```

which implements the XMPP specification (see https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#int for details).
The buddy can accept subscription replying with:

```
connection.send($pres({
  to: from,  // jid of subscriber
  type: "subscribed"
}));
```

You can check my web client example based on XMPP (using Strophe.js) on Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/EhQHDsYpDhrECmaaIlZO

Comment: Thanks for your response. i just add subscription plugin to open fire and set auto subscriber. and now its working fine... your answer is also what i want to know. thanks buddy.

Comment: is it possible to to create video chat using strophe.js or any other lib with openfire?

Comment: I can only suggest you to check for WebRTC features which enable web browser to do realtime audio/video communication among peers

Comment: So you can use XMPP as a signalling way to control realtime communication (search for XMPP Jingle, strophe jingle, ...)

Comment: thanks.. let me check.. i think TURN is possible in openfire via plugin.